# What do the instal and active options do when adding a static route in JunOS?

Tags: routing, juniper, juniper-junos

In the command completion there is:

```
  active               Remove inactive route from forwarding table
  [...]
  install              Install route into forwarding table
```

I can create static routes with or without them and it seems to make no difference. They still get redistributed. What are the practical implications of enabling those options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INSTALL**

> Configure whether Junos OS installs all static routes into the
>   forwarding table. Even if you configure a route so it is not installed
>   in the forwarding table, the route is still eligible to be exported
>   from the routing table to other protocols.

**ACTIVE**

> Determine whether static, aggregate, or generated routes are removed
>   from the routing and forwarding tables when they become inactive.
>   Static routes are only removed from the routing table if the next hop
>   becomes unreachable. This can occur if the local or neighbor interface
>   goes down. Routes that have been configured to remain continually
>   installed in the routing and forwarding tables are marked with reject
>   next hops when they are inactive

This information has been taken from the juniper techlibrary site. Links provided below.

[Active Option](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.1/topics/reference/configuration-statement/active-edit-routing-options.html)

[Install Option](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.1/topics/reference/configuration-statement/install-edit-routing-options.html)